# Gdx.files.internal(...) wrapper not working correctly

Tags: java, file, libgdx, bufferedreader

I made a wrapper `ConfigurationFile` class to help handle `Gdx.files` stuff, and it worked fine for a long time, but now it's not working, and I don't know why.

I have two of the following two methods: `internal(...)` and `local(...)`. The only difference between the two is handling the load from arguments from `(File folder, String name)` and `(String path)`.

-Snip Now Unnecessary Information-

---

**UPDATE**
After more configuring, I came to find out that they're not behaving the same. I have an `assets/files/` folder that `Gdx.files.internal(...)` will access fine, but `ConfigurationFile.internal(...)` will access `files/`, and they're set up the same way. I'll give you the two pieces of code that I used for testing.

Using `Gdx.files.internal(...)` directly (works as expected):

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("files/virus_data");
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(handle.reader());
    String c = "";
    while ((c = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(c); // prints out all 5 lines on the file.
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (reader != null) reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using `ConfigurationFile.internal(...)`:

```
// First part, calls ConfigurationFile#internal(String path)
ConfigurationFile config = ConfigurationFile.internal("files/virus_data");

// ConfigurationFile#internal(String path)
public static ConfigurationFile internal(String path) {
    ConfigurationFile config = new ConfigurationFile();
    // This is literally calling Gdx.files.internal("files/virus_data");
    config.handle = Gdx.files.internal(path);
    config.file = config.handle.file();
    config.folder = config.file.getParentFile();
    config.init();
    return config;
}

// ConfigurationFile#init()
protected void init() {
    // File not found.
    // Creates a new folder as a sibling of "assets"
    // Creates a new file called "virus_data"
    if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else loadFile();
}

// ConfigurationFile#loadFile()
protected void loadFile() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(handle.reader());
        String c = "";
        while ((c = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(c);
            if (!c.contains(":")) continue;
            String[] values = c.split(":");
            String key = values[0];
            String value = values[1];
            if (values.length > 2) {
                for (int i = 2; i < values.length; i++) {
                    value += ":" + values[i];
                }
            }
            key = key.trim();
            value = value.trim();
            mapValues.put(key, value);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is what's the difference between these two ways that it is causing my `ConfigurationFile` to create a new File in a folder that is a sibling of `assets`. Could someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Post updated with the newest information that I have for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after intense testing, I found out the problem, which I found to be ridiculous.

Since the file is `Internal`, that means a `new File(...)` reference can't be properly made to it, but instead it's an `InputStream` (if I'm correct), but anyways, using the method `FileHandle#file()` on an `Internal` file causes some kind of conversion for the path, so after removing anything that dealed with `FileHandle#file()` for an `Internal` file fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use

```
Gdx.files.internal(folder + "/" + name);
```

If you have to use the File api, do it this way:

```
Gdx.files.internal(new File(folder, name).toString());
```

This way you avoid weird things that could be happening with path separators.

If Gdx maybe needs relative paths for some reason (perhaps relative to some Gdx internal home directory), you could use NIO to do something like

```
final Path gdxHome = Paths.get("path/to/gdx/home");

//...

File combined = new File(folder, name);
String relativePath = gdxHome.relativize(combined.toPath()).toString();
```

Comment: That could be one thing, but that the `internal` and `external` methods that call for `(File folder, String name)` as the parameters just kind of sit there for now.; I just use the path currently to register my files, so that would make no difference.